# Is there a better way to get a uid in a block than using Input Format PHP?

Tags: blocks, input-formats

I need to make a direct link to page which needs the uid in the URL.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this in a block? Does Input Format PHP code open some unnecessary attack vectors? Are input filters or tokens in blocks possible?

```
<?php 
global $user; 
?>   
.
.
.
<li>
   <a href="/user/<?php echo $user->uid ?>/fboauth?destination=stream">Facebook Deauthorize</a>
</li>
```

This is a legacy site running 6.28 using [FBOauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth).

Comment: What is the block for that you need to use `Input Format PHP`? You should be creating your own block module for blocks that require custom PHP. Custom PHP inside any kind of form is an issue.

Comment: So custom hook_block() with the content of the block sent through $block['content'] => $custom_content; ?

Comment: Yes :) that is what I meant.

Comment: Wanna throw that in the answer below?

Comment: +5 for asking if there's a better way than php module. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be creating your own block module for blocks that require custom PHP, custom PHP inside a form field is not very good security wise because of the way the PHP is parsed.

A custom block meaning

`custom_hook_block()` with the `$block['content'] =>`

Comment: Here is a great example of how to do this http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2012/07/18/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7